# Magento http://localhost/images should be http://localhost/mysite/images

Tags: apache, magento

Hi there i'm new to magento,

So I have migrated a site from the web to my localhost.

- I have set db settings.
- I have changed the unsecure and secure base urls in the db.
- I deleted the folders in var/cache

The site is working fine except for when I load it up it is reffering to the images folder as localhost/images when it should be localhost/mysite/images

firebug errors example below:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/images/icons/world1.png"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/images/bullet9c.png"

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Look in your admin panel under System -> Configuration. Somewhere under the web tab on the left you can set the base URL for images. (Sorry I cannot be more specific, but I am not connected to my live instance of Magento)